# Passing a Parcelable Object which contains an array of Parcelable Objects

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

I'd like to pass a Parcelable object which contains an array of Parcelable objects; my problem is that despite the second activity starts the return object is null. I call the Activity this way:

```
i=new Intent(SoNActivity.this,OperationListAct.class);
i.putExtra("1", opSettings);
startActivityForResult(i, CommunicationConfig.getRequestCode(SoNActivity.class));
```

The opSetting object is an instance of the OperationSetting class, which has as attribute an array of objects:

```
public class OperationSetting implements Parcelable{
    public class OperationInfo implements Parcelable{
            private Operation mOperation;
            private boolean mActive;
            private int mPosition;
            private String mName;
            private String mDescription;


            public OperationInfo(boolean isAct,int pos,String name, String descr,Operation op){
                    mActive=isAct;
                    mPosition =pos;
                    mName=name;
                    mDescription=descr;
                    mActive=true;
                    mOperation=op;
            }

            public Operation getOperation(){return mOperation;}
            public boolean getActive(){return mActive;}
            public int getPosition(){return mPosition;}
            public String getName(){return mName;}
            public String getDescription(){return mDescription;}

            public void setOperation(Operation operation){mOperation=operation;}
            public void setActive(boolean active){mActive=active;}
            public void setPosition(int position){mPosition=position;}
            public void setName(String name){mName=name;}
            public void setDescription(String description){mDescription=description;}

            private String[] getAttList(){
                    String[] atts={"name","description","position","isEnabled","operation"};
                    return atts;
            }



            public int describeContents() {
                    return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
                    Bundle bndl=new Bundle();
                    String[] attList=this.getAttList();
                    bndl.putString(attList[0], mName);
                    bndl.putString(attList[1],mDescription);
                    bndl.putInt(attList[2],mPosition);
                    bndl.putBoolean(attList[3], mActive);
                    bndl.putString(attList[4], mOperation.toString());
                    out.writeBundle(bndl);

            }

        public OperationInfo (Parcel in) {
            Bundle bndl = in.readBundle();
            String[] attList=this.getAttList();
            mName=bndl.getString(attList[0]);
            mDescription=bndl.getString(attList[1]);
            mPosition=bndl.getInt(attList[2]);
            mActive=bndl.getBoolean(attList[3]);
            mOperation=Operation.valueOf(bndl.getString(attList[4]));
        }

        public final Parcelable.Creator<OperationInfo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<OperationInfo>() {
                 public OperationInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                     return new OperationInfo(in);
                 }

                 public OperationInfo[] newArray(int size) {
                     return new OperationInfo[size];
                 }
        };


    }

    private OperationInfo[] m_settings;



    public OperationSetting (String[] namesOp,String[] descrOp,int[] positions, boolean[] enabled,boolean firstExec){
            Operation[] opList=Operation.values();
            m_settings=new OperationInfo[opList.length];
            for(int i=0;i<opList.length;i++){
                    m_settings[i]=new OperationInfo(enabled[i], positions[i], namesOp[i], descrOp[i], opList[i]);
            }
            if(firstExec){
                    String[] newOrder=namesOp.clone();
                    Arrays.sort(newOrder);
                    this.sort(newOrder);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeParcelableArray(m_settings, flags);
    }

public OperationSetting(Parcel in) {
    m_settings = (OperationInfo[]) in.readParcelableArray(OperationInfo.class.getClassLoader());

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<OperationSetting> CREATOR= new Parcelable.Creator<OperationSetting>() {
    public OperationSetting createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new OperationSetting(in);
    }

    public OperationSetting[] newArray(int size) {
            return new OperationSetting[size];
    }
};}
```

Finally, to take back the object from the second Activity I wrote:

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
            OperationSetting op=b.getParcelable("1");
```

The second Activity runs fine, but when I try to get the object I get an java.lang.outOfMemory Exception; it crashes on the method OperationSetting(Parcel in). What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure whether what you are trying will ever work because if your class implements Parcelable then it should have a **static field** CREATOR and that is not possible with your model since inner classes can't have static fields. How about putting OperationInfo in another class altogether and then trying?

The OutOfMemory error might be due to a recursive call to OperatorSettings(in) which is causing a stack overflow (giggle!).